# How to exclude commented line/text in finding procedure with Text in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two procedures as shown below.

```
Create proc FirstProcdure
As
begin
    select * from MyTableA
    --select * from MyTableB    
end
```

and

```
Create proc SecondProcdure
As
begin
    select * from MyTableB
    --select * from MyTableA    
end
```

Now I want to search procedure with text - `MyTableA`. It should only come 'FirstProcdure' in result because in 'SecondProcdure' the
text `MyTableA` is commented.

I have tried using below query

```
Select * from sysobjects where OBJECT_DEFINITION (id) like '%MyTableA%'
```

Currently it is giving both procedure name in search result.

Sometime we need to change procedure definition quickly & then it is difficult to open find and replace several procedures. So I need to search only procedure name for which the searched text is not the part of commented lines.

Comment: You have to come up with a coding style which allows you to exclude commented out code. There is nothing in SQL to do it for you. Assuming you can't do `not like '%--select * from MyTableA %'` you may need to leave yourself a comment e.g. `-- Exclude MyTableA` and then you can do `not like '%Exclude TableA%'`

Comment: @DaleBurrell It is not fixed 'select * from' because it may be empCd in where condition and so on...

Comment: Like '%'+char(10)+'%[^-]%MyTableA'  --START from the newline, check there is not a -, look for the table name. or drop MyTableA, run all the procs and see which fail..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the custom function for ignore comment text search.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SearchCommentText(@Value VARCHAR(MAX),@SearchText VARCHAR(MAX))  
RETURNS INT   
AS   
BEGIN  
   DECLARE @cursor INT = 0,@ret INT=0
   declare @commenttext varchar(max)=''
    WHILE PATINDEX('%--%', @Value) > 0 OR    PATINDEX('%/*%', @Value) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF CHARINDEX('--', @Value, 0)BETWEEN 1 AND CHARINDEX('/*', @Value, 0)
            OR    CHARINDEX('/*', @Value, 0) = 0
        BEGIN

            SET @commenttext=@commenttext+ SUBSTRING( @Value,CHARINDEX('--', @Value), ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), @Value, CHARINDEX('--',@Value)), 0), LEN(@Value)) - CHARINDEX('--', @Value) + 2)
            SET @Value = STUFF(@Value, CHARINDEX('--', @Value), ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), @Value, CHARINDEX('--', @Value)), 0), LEN(@Value)) - CHARINDEX('--', @Value) + 2, '') ;

        END ;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @cursor = -1 ;
            WHILE CHARINDEX('/*', @Value, @cursor + 1)BETWEEN 1 AND CHARINDEX('*/', @Value, @cursor + 1)
            SET @cursor = CHARINDEX('/*', @Value, @cursor + 1) ;

            set @commenttext=@commenttext+SUBSTRING(@Value, @cursor, CHARINDEX('*/', @Value, @cursor) - @cursor + 2);
            SET @Value = STUFF(@Value, @cursor, CHARINDEX('*/', @Value, @cursor) - @cursor + 2, '') ;
        END ;
    END ;
    IF(@commenttext LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%' AND @Value NOT LIKE  '%'+@SearchText+'%')
    SET @ret=1;

    RETURN @ret;  
END;
```

Execute the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(sc.id)  FROM syscomments sc
WHERE TEXT like '%MyTableA%' AND dbo.SearchCommentText(sc.text,'MyTableA') <>1
```

Comment: Let me check and will reply.

Comment: @Alex, Thank you for the Update. I have checked both single line and multi line comments.

Comment: @Mano Thank you for your valuable effort and it will save my time in future.

Comment: @Mano It needed some more condition when text appears in both commented and not commented lines.

Comment: @Mano In this proc https://rextester.com/KCBC79003 the text MyTableA is in both commented and uncommented lines so it should also come in result.

Comment: I have altered the function and added condition. Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for a dataobject used in other dataobject is a dependency, so, is too much easier to do it directly

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id) FROM sys.sysdepends WHERE depid = OBJECT_ID('MyTableA')
```

If you want to search for a string or another thing that is not dataobject related (For example, depends will not detect if you call your table using dynamic SQL). I prefer to use `sp_helptext` instead of `OBJECT_DEFINITION`, if you don't have objections using a loop

```
DECLARE @SearchFor VARCHAR(100) = 'MyTableA'
DECLARE @Objects TABLE(name varchar(100))
DECLARE @Result TABLE(name varchar(100))
DECLARE @Lines TABLE(id int identity, line varchar(maX))

INSERT @Objects
SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE Type in ('FN', 'IF', 'V', 'P', 'TR', 'TF') 

DECLARE @ObjectName VARCHAR(100)
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Objects)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @ObjectName = name FROM @Objects

    DELETE @Lines

    INSERT @Lines (line)
    exec sp_helptext @ObjectName

    --Wipe out multiline comments
    DECLARE @Linestart INT, @indexStart INT, @LineEnd INT, @indexEnd INT
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @Lines WHERE charindex('/*', line) > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @Linestart = id, @indexStart = charindex('/*', line)
        FROM @Lines WHERE charindex('/*', line) > 0
        ORDER BY id

        SELECT TOP 1 @LineEnd = id, @indexEnd = charindex('*/', line)
        FROM @Lines WHERE charindex('*/', line) > 0
        ORDER BY id

        IF @Linestart = @LineEnd
            UPDATE @Lines SET line = SUBSTRING(line, 1, @indexStart-1) + SUBSTRING(line, @indexEnd+2, LEN(line))
            WHERE id = @Linestart
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE @Lines SET line = SUBSTRING(line, 1, @indexStart-1)
            WHERE id = @Linestart
            UPDATE @Lines SET line = SUBSTRING(line, @indexEnd+2, LEN(line))
            WHERE id = @LineEnd
            DELETE @Lines WHERE id > @Linestart AND id < @LineEnd
        END
    END

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM @Lines
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT charindex(@SearchFor, line) A, charindex ('--', line) B
        ) S
        WHERE A > 0 AND (B = 0 OR A < B) )
    BEGIN
        INSERT @Result VALUES (@ObjectName)
    END


    DELETE @Objects WHERE name = @ObjectName
END
SELECT * FROM @Result
```